# MVC5 Country/State dropdownlist for Edits

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working up a an edit page for our MVC app with Country and State dropdowns. I have the drop downs populating. Country get's loaded on page load, and when a country is selected the State list gets loaded. When editing, the Country list is filled and properly selected.

My question is how do I set the State to be selected. Here's what I have so far:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    @Html.LabelForRequired(model => model.CountryId, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label"})
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryId,
        new SelectList(ViewBag.Countries as IEnumerable, "CountryId", "CountryName"),
        new {@class = "form-control", id = "ddlCountry"})
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CountryId, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    @Html.LabelForRequired(model => model.State, new {@class = "control-label"})
    <select id="ddlState" name="@Html.NameFor(model => model.State)"></select>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.State, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
</div>
```

Here's my script:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        LoadStates();

        $("#ddlCountry").change(function () {
            LoadStates();
        });
    });

    function LoadStates() {
        var Param = { CountryId: $("#ddlCountry > option:selected").attr("value") };
        $.getJSON(appFolder + "Home/StateList/", Param, function (data) {
            var items = "<option>Select State</option>";
            $.each(data, function (i, state) {
                items += "<option value=" + state.StateCode + ">" + state.State + "</option>";
            });
            $("#ddlState").html(items);
        });
    }
</script>
```

I've been looking for an example, but haven't found one.

Comment: I like that. How long will it stay on DotNetFiddle?

Answer (score 1):

While you could modify the code in the success callback to include `$("#ddlState").val(someValue);` where `someValue` might be a model or `ViewBag` property, you current implementation (manually creating the `<select>` element means you do not get strong typed binding and do not get client side validation.

Instead, generate the `SelectList` in the controller (which may be an empty `SelectList` in the case of a `Create` view) and pass it to the model. Note its always preferable to use view models, but the following could be modified to use `ViewBag` properties for the SelectLists

View model

```
public class ViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Country")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a country")]
    public int? CountryID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "State")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a state")]
    public int? StateID { get; set; }
    .... // other properties needed for the view
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CountryList { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> StateList { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
private void ConfigureViewModel(ViewModel model)
{
    var countries = db.Countries;
    model.CountryList = new SelectList(countries, "CountryId", "CountryName");
    if (model.StateID.HasValue)
    {
        var states = db.States.Where(s => s.CountryId == model.StateID.Value);
        model.StateList = new SelectList(states, "StateId", "StateName");
    }
    else
    {
        model.StateList = new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>());
    }
}

public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewModel model = new ViewModel();
    ConfigureViewModel(model);
    return View(model);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ConfigureViewModel(model);
        return View(model);
    }
    // Initialize data model and set its properties based on view model
    // Save data model and redirect
}
public ActionResult Edit(int ID)
{
    // Get data model based on ID
    ViewModel model = new ViewModel();
    // Set properties based on data model
    ConfigureViewModel(model);
    return View(model);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ConfigureViewModel(model);
        return View(model);
    }
    // Get data model and set its properties based on view model
    // Save data model and redirect
}
```

and in the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CountryID, Model.CountryList, new {@class = "form-control"})
....
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StateID, Model.StateList, new {@class = "form-control"})

var url = '@Url.Action("StateList", "Home")'; // don't hard code your url's
var states = $('StateID'); // cache it
$('#CountryID').change(function() {
    states.empty();
    $.getJSON(url, { CountryId: $(this).val() }, function(data) { // use $(this)
    if (!data) {
        return;
    }
    // add empty option with value="" so you get client side validation
    states.append($('<option></option>').val('').text('Please select'));
    $.each(data, function(index, item) {
        subLocalities.append($('<option></option>').val(item.StateCode ).text(item.State));
    });
});
```